# Media Library Image Sizes in Bones theme (add_image_size)

Tags: thumbnails, images

I'd like to create new thumbnail options in Bones and have followed the instructions in the Bones theme Functions.php file. I am expecting therefore that one should be able to choose from the Size Dropdown menu the new thumbnail I have set like this. (note, the default wp sizes is showing)

[image]

taken from this example http://www.limecanvas.com/adding-custom-image-sizes-to-wordpress-3-5-media-manager/

Am I misunderstanding how it works in Bones perhaps? These are the instructions from the Functions.php file.

> To call a different size, simply change the text
>   inside the thumbnail function.
>
> For example, to call the 300 x 300 sized image, we would use the
>   function:  for the
>   600 x 100 image:

But I don't want to be use the PHP code, rather a specific size from the dropdown menu as mentioned from the Add Media (Media Library) as above

Many thanks

**EDIT:**

In the Bones theme, this is where the *add_image_size* is added:
https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones/blob/master/functions.php
And this is where the *add_theme_support* function is called:
https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones/blob/master/library/bones.php

**EDIT:**
I can see that the images are being generated so that part is working. I just don't get the dropdown option to choose the images from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you needed to add this additional hook into your functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'your-custom-size' => __('Your Custom Size Name'),
    ) );
}
```

Soon as I did that the image sizes appeared in the dropdown menu.
Solution here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#For_Media_Library_Images_.28Admin.29

Answer (score 0):

If your theme already includes:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Then you can just add a new size in functions:

```
add_image_size('custom', 70, 70, TRUE);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Comment: Thanks Brad, I have added an EDIT above to explain where Bones theme is already doing this.

Comment: I think that answers your question?

Comment: If only it did ;) But I've applied this and found it not working.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress already includes some default image sizes so the drop down should be there regardless of theme.

Here is what you should do.

First change theme to a default theme (2012,2013, etc..)
Then try to insert an image in your post. 
If the drop down is there it's your theme.
If it's not there start deactivating plugins checking each time you deactivate one.
If that doesn't work go to http://wordpress.org download the latest version and overwrite all of your core files.

If it is your theme try re-downloading and overwrite your theme files. If you have made changes to the themes code try and trace back your steps and note your changes and keep the broken theme in a backup for comparison with the freshly downloaded theme.

This should get you on the right track.

Comment: Hi Jacob. The dropdown is there. It's the for the default image sizes. What I need however is for the dropdown to show the new custom image sizes I am setting up through the add_image_size function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Specifically I am trying to get it to work through the Bones Theme.